# Thinkpad Battery drops at 40%

Tags: power-management, battery

Recently I observed the following on my Thinkpad X230 with Ubuntu 16.04 on it:

When I use the Laptop and the charger is not plugged in, I observe battery drops from around 40% to 5%. It seems like I can use the full charged battery only from 100% to ~40%.

**What could be the reason for this? Is there anything I can do about it?**

The following screenshots capture the problem.

Charge graph:
[image: Charge graph]

Time-To-Empty graph:
[image: Time-To-Empty graph]

And finally some Details about my battery:
[image: Details]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The battery needs to be calibrated. In Macs, usually the way to do it is letting it drain, charging it in one go without using it, and then using it non-stop until you drain the battery again. No ideia about Thinkpads. This is not a Unix problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a BIOS or hardware issue as there is no Linux Battery Reconditioning software...

Comment: @guntbert Comment removed and close vote retracted and answer upvoted.  **:-)** *I bow to your wisdom.*

Answer (score 4):

It is highly probable that the ideas your battery has about its status don't align with its real status any more.

What you need to do is "recalibrate" the battery, by completely discharging the battery and then recharging it to 100%.

The optimal tool for battery management on your thinkpad is `tlp` .

From `man tlp` (which you should read anyway)

> For ThinkPads it provides a unified way to configure charging thresholds and
>    recalibrate the battery for all models which support it (via tp-smapi or
>    acpi-call).

Install it via

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

To recalibrate the battery: `sudo tlp recalibrate`

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical symptom of a defective battery cell. Replace the battery.

Recalibration (with TLP) doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Clarification might be necessary. If you have battery damage, re-calibration can help to get a more accurate display of remaining battery, but it cannot fix the damage or restore battery capacity to what it was previously - only replacing the battery can.

Comment: Recalibration does not help to get a more accurate display. Battery controllers can not cope with a defective cell.